# My image is displaying in Chrome & Firefox, but not safari or iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, safari

I have created a video thumbnail image which, when clicked, triggers a video autoplay hidden behind it. The video/image thumbnail are also both responsive, and adjust to changes in browser size.

The functionality works fine on Chrome & Firefox on Desktop, but not safari. Furthermore, it doesn't work on my iPhone 4s in both the Chrome and Safari app.

This does not have to do with Safari not handling large images, because my image is only 416 × 234.

EDIT: I should add that the autoplay feature remains intact. Whenever I click where the img should be on the screen, autoplay begins. This even works in mobile (albeit without autoplay, as that is not mobile supported). It's also not an extension/naming issue, as the image is being loaded by the safari browser when I inspect the source code.

Relevant HTML:

```
<div id="video-thumbnail">
    <img src="norman.png" class="video-image" alt=""/> 
    <iframe class="video-embed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?rel=0&color=white&controls=1&showinfo=0" s8011508427261248624="true" replaced="true" ></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#video-thumbnail {
     position: relative;
     padding-bottom: 56.25%;
     padding-top: 55px;
     height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
}

.video-image {
     position: relative;
     content: "";
     cursor: pointer;
     z-index: 5;
}

.video-embed {
     display: none;
     opacity: 0;
     z-index: 10;
}

.video-image, .video-embed {
     position: absolute;
     top:0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     padding: 60px 60px 80px 60px;
}
```

JS:

```
 (function($){
      $(document).ready( function(){
           $(".video-image").click(function(){
           $(".video-embed").css({"opacity":"1","display":"block"});
           $(".video-embed")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
           $(this).unbind("click");
          });
      } );
  })(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered my own question. Removal of the line

```
content: "";
```

from the CSS for .video-image did the trick. This was mistakenly copied over from a previous example. Interesting enough, the JS handled the presence of this tag differently in Chrome & Firefox differently than in Safari. Not experienced enough in JS to fully-understand why, I'd love an explanation if someone has one.

Answer (score 0):

So this is not really a fix since you already answered the question yourself but since you seemed interested the JS is handled under different regulations by default on each modern browser. Hence in this example,

```
content : " ";
```

makes chrome and firefox take the default value while safari probably does not allow *empty strings* to be used in their JS handlers. If you're more interested on how this works in detail, these links will help you out.

https://www.quora.com/Why-do-different-browsers-process-CSS3-HTML-5-and-JavaScript-differently  and this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243074/how-is-it-that-javascript-can-function-differently-from-browser-to-browser)